# how to use same model class in different modules of my rest APIs

Tags: spring, rest

## Background

I have one spring boot application for REST API where i have to create rest based microservices .
for different rest i have to pass request body as json data.
The request json data e.g:

1.

`{
    "query":"",
    "variables": {
        "input": {
            "name": "",
            "description": "",
            "gitUrl": "",
            "repoName": ""
        }
    }
}`

2. 

`{
    "query":"",
    "variables": {
        "input": {
            "name": ""
              }
    }
}`

3.

 `{
    "query":"",
    "variables": {
          "search": ""
    }
}`

I do not want to pass all parameters as request body in my API,some has just Query,Variables,Input some has just Query and variables like above json data
I want to create same model which can be used in all the rest apis. For now i have created different models for each API.

1. Create Request:

   ## #

   public class CreatetRequest {

   ```
   private String query;
   private Variables variables;
   ```

   }

## #

```
public class Variables {

    private Input input;
}
```

## #

```
public class Input {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String gitUrl;
    private String repoName;
}
```

## #

Here i am duplicating my model in all the APIs,so i want to create three model classes with all the required variables which will be common throughout my boot application but at the same time i have to avoid sending all the data in request body.of my rest api.

What could be the best way in spring application to avoid such boiler-plate code

Comment: If you don't set values to these model classes then it goes null in JSON request so is that fine for you or you need not null fields in JSON data.

Comment: you could make these fields Optional if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I don't want in my request body all data.

Comment: That should be fine with Optionals as well. Also you could use annotation - `JsonInclude` for NotNull fields only.

Comment: Problem is I have to develop different api based on the request body,so I am wondering how to avoid unwanted parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface with @JsonDeserialize annotations

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonDeserialize(using = InputDeserializer.class)
public interface InputInterface {

}
```

Input object type 1 that implements this interface

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonDeserialize(as = Type1.class)
public class Type1 implements InputInterface {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String gitUrl;
    private String repoName;

    // setters, getters, constructor
}
```

Input object type 2 that implements this interface

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonDeserialize(as = Type2.class)
public class Type2 implements InputInterface{

    String name;

    // setters, getters, constructor
}
```

Implement a deserializer for the interface

In the deserialize method you check which type of input is by the parameters present in the request body.

Here for simplify we just use two types.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class InputDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<InputInterface> {

       @Override
        public InputInterface deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
            ObjectNode root = mapper.readTree(jp);

            /* 
                  Write your conditions here 
                  to check what type of input is

             */
            if (root.has("name") && root.has("description")) {
                return mapper.readValue(root.toString(), Type1.class);
            } else {
                return mapper.readValue(root.toString(), Type2.class);
            }

        }

}
```

Use the interface in your controller

```
@PostMapping()
public void save(@RequestBody InputInterface input) throws Exception {
    // save the customer using service
    System.out.println(input);

}
```

This was just to show  how it's working, adapt it to your needs :-)